Finding the value of $a$ and $n$ if $x^3-x^2+ax-2^n=0$ has three integral solutions
By using Vieta's formula I only went so far as to calculate the following
$r_1+r_2+r_3=1$
$r_1 r_2+r_2 r_3+r_3 r_1=a$
$r_1r_2r_3=2^n$
From here, I tried doing some casework but couldn't proceed. Can you help me to get to a rigorous solution?

Can you give us more information about what you did?

What is $n$? ...........

$r_1r_2r_3=2^n\Rightarrow r_i=s_i 2^{n_i}$ where $s_i\in{-1, 1}$ then we have $s_1s_2s_3=1$ and $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$. See to first equation!

Suppose $n$ is nonnegative integer.
From first equation at least one $r_i$, say $r_1$ must be odd, so it is 1 or -1. Let $r=r_2$.

$r_1=1$ then $r_3=-r_2$ so $-r^2 = 2^n$ which is impossible.
$r_1=-1$ then $r_3=2-r_2$ so $(r-2)r = 2^n$  so
$$r-2 = 2^b\;\; \wedge\;\; r=2^c\implies 2^c-2^b=2$$
for some nonegative integers $b<c$. Then $$2^b(2^{c-b}-1)=2\implies b=1\;\; \wedge \;\;2^{c-1}-1=1 $$ and so $c=2$ and thus $n=3$. So $a$ is...


the roots must divide $2^n$ so the roots are of the form $\pm 2^k$
$r_1r_2r_3 > 0$ so an even number of roots are negative (i.e. $0$ or $2$ negative roots)
The sum of the roots equals 1, eliminating the possibility of 3 positive roots.
Since the sum of the roots is 1, at least one root must be odd ($\pm 1$)
If one root is $+1$, then the sum of the other roots is $0.$  But, that leaves us with one negative root.
One root is $-1.$  The sum of the two remaining roots is $2$ and one of those two is negative.
$(r_1,r_2,r_3) = (4,-2,-1)$

HINT:

That $r_1r_2r_3 = 2^n$ with $r_1,r_2,r_3$ integral implies that all must be powers of $2$ times $\pm 1$. That and the condition $r_1+r_2+r_3=1$ narrows down the choices [up to the order of $r_1,r_2,r_3$ that is] to $r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = -r_3$, OR $r_1=r_2=r_3=1$ OR [as Will Jagy noted] $r_1=-1,r_2=-2,r_3=4$.

If $r_2=-r_3$ and $r_1=1$, then $r_1r_2r_3 = -r_2^2$ is negative. So $r_1=r_2=r_3=1$ or $r_1=-1,r_2=-2,r_3=4$ is the only possible solution.

Then however $r_1=r_2 = r_3 = 1$ gives $r_1r_2+r_2r_3 +r_1r_2$ would be $3$. So that is out.

Can you conclude that $r_1=-1,r_2=-2,r_3=4$ is the only solution, and $(x+1)(x+2)(x-4)$ works, and so $a=-10$.



@Moo yes I apologize for my mistake. $r_1=1, r_2=-r_3$ does not work as then $r_1r_2r_3$ is negative. Thanks for the catch!

4-2-1  = 1 .........

Because of $r_1+r_2+r_3=1$ with integers, it is plausible to consider $r_1+r_2=0$ and $r_3=1$ so we have $$x^2(x-1)+ax+2^n=0$$ which yields in fact infinitely many solutions
$$(a,n)=(-2^{2k},2k) \text{ for } k\in\mathbb N$$

The worst thing about math is calling something good bad. Who is the idiot who voted against it? For $k=1$ the roots are $(-2,1,2)$; for $k=2$ you have roots $(-4,1,4)$; for $k=3$ there are $(-8,1,8)$. In general for  $k$ arbitrary natural you have the roots $(-2^k,1,2^k)$. I'll don't delete my answer which stay as something not desirable in MSE
